# Visual Studio optimisations break SDL graphical output

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, sdl-2

When compiling my Chip-8 Emulator that uses SDL-2 in Visual Studio with optimisations on, the SDL window fails to display any graphics. The SDL window works completely when compiling without optimisation.

I have disassembled the binary files to see if I could figure out what exactly the optimiser is doing and the only difference between the optimised code and unoptimised code when disassembled is two rdata lines as follows:

Optimised:

```
.rdata:140006914 2f                               0x2f '/'
.rdata:140006915 55                               0x55 'U'
```

Unoptimised:

```
.rdata:140006914 ce                               0xce 
.rdata:140006915 56                               0x56 'V'
```

I do not have much experience with x86 assembly and so do not understand what this difference would entail and why it breaks things.

Additionally, reverting to a previous commit that I think worked breaks in the same way, and using a previously compiled binary that worked does the same. This makes me wonder if this is possibly an issue that has come from Windows.

How exactly would these two rdata lines be effecting the application so significantly and how would I go about fixing this?

- [Git Repo](https://git.omkov.net/Jamozed/C8E)
- [Optimised Disassembly](https://p.teknik.io/0A9fo)
- [Unoptimised Disassembly](https://p.teknik.io/xHOqV)

Comment: `do not have much experience with x86 assembly` well, .rdata is for (read-only) data, not for x86 instructions. So look at the initialization data and search for those bytes, maybe you'll get a clue

Comment: Look at them as decimals, hex, part of a string, revert them (LE vs BE) ...

Comment: As always, we need a [mcve].

Comment: Maybe a better way to go about this is to debug the un-compiled code and see if there is something wrong there...

Comment: A quick look at the source code makes me suspect major problems with threads. E.g. a "chip8.drawFlag" that's being used by multiple threads, isn't protected by any kind of lock/mutex, isn't atomic and isn't even volatile.

Comment: That could do it; debug-mode makes all variables act kind of like `volatile`.  When compiling for an ISA like x86 with strong memory ordering, that sort of gives you  acquire/release semantics. [MCU programming - C++ O2 optimization breaks while loop](//electronics.stackexchange.com/a/387478) explains why it's UB and what the consequence is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure of the exact problem, but...

When the compiler sees something like this:

```
int loopDisplay(void) {
    while (running) {
        if (chip8.drawFlag) {
            UpdateDisplay();              // Update Display
            chip8.drawFlag = false;       // Reset Draw Flag
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It will look up the details for variables like `chip8.drawFlag`, realize there's nothing special about it (it's a plain `boolean drawFlag;`); and then optimize the code to be more like this (where `temp` is possibly just value in one of the CPU's registers):

```
int loopDisplay(void) {
    temp = chip8.drawFlag;
    while (running) {
        if (temp) {
            UpdateDisplay();              // Update Display
            temp = false;                 // Reset Draw Flag
        }
    }
    chip8.drawFlag = temp;
    return 0;
}
```

Then it will realize it can optimize it more, and maybe come up with something like this:

```
int loopDisplay(void) {
    temp = chip8.drawFlag;
    if(running && temp) 
         UpdateDisplay();              // Update Display
        }
    }
    while(running) {}
    chip8.drawFlag = false;
    return 0;
}
```

Of course if `running` is also just a plain old variable, then it can decide that the function will either do nothing and return immediately, or loop forever (and never do the `chip8.drawFlag = false` and never return).

To fix these kinds of problems (where 2 or more threads use the same things without any synchronization) you'll need to tell the compiler that the variables are special (e.g. acquire a lock before using them, or make them atomic). You'll have to go through all your code and find all the problems.

Comment: Looks like I need to work on my thread safety, adding thread locking or making the draw flag atomic fixes my issue. Thanks.